# excel file values are not updating

Tags: c#, vba, excel, macros

In my application i have an excel sheet with button. Using C# code i'm calling the button of excel file and the excel file click event also working very fine. I placed msg box in macros in that way i verified the click event of the excel sheet button working fine.But after running the macro the values are not updating in excel sheet. Please refer my code below ,

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:test.xlsm", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlApp.Run("Module1.solver", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
xlWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 xlApp.Quit();
releaseObject(xlApp);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
            obj = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Am I missing some function to update excel file ? And the macros I'm using are

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$A$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$4:$A$6", _
    apple:=1, applecurry:="GRG Nonlinear"
MsgBox "$3"
SolverOk SetCell:="$A$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$4:$A$6", _
    apple:=1, applecurry:="GRG Nonlinear"
MsgBox "$4"
SolverSolve
```

Comment: Have you checked Options>Formulas to make sure you have automatic workbook calculation selected? I sometimes turn this off programmtically!

Comment: This: `xlWorkBook.Close(false` is quit without saving, is that your intention?

Comment: @AlexK. : i tried by given true also , but the values are not updating

Comment: @MiguelH : i verified Options->Formulas , "Automatic" option is already selected. if i click the button in excel sheet the values are updating , but not via source code . But both calling same macro functions only

Answer (score 0):

When you start Excel via automation, any add-ins or items in the xlstart folder are not loaded.

If your code relies on add-ins being loaded, then you will need to load them via your code.

See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213489